# Pause/Stop or remove HTML5 video on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I currently have a responsive HTML banner that has video (utilizing the video tag) inside of it. My unit is responsive as the entire thing will scale and so will the video. I have a breakpoint setup that turns on new divs when the window is closed below 820px. This is accomplished via

```
 @media (max-width:820px) {

//css is here
}
```

I'd like to include either javascript of jquery that also removes or pauses the video when this size is reached just so the video doesn't continue to play out of sight. My simple:

```
  .ad_div2
 {
 display:none;
 }
```

where the video element lives simply hides that div but you can still hear the video playing in the background.

I've tried a couple of things but not sure that I'm setting it up right.

```
 <script>
 var parent=document.getElementById("div1");
 var child=document.getElementById("p1");
 parent.removeChild(child);
 </script>
```

(with my appropriate id names) and that within my @media tag isn't doing it - maybe i've placed this in the wrong area or it's not quite what I need.

Any help would, as always, be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#videoId").remove()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a listener on the window resize event.

```
$(function() {
    var videoElement = document.getElementById('yourVideoID'),
        $window      = $(window);

    $window.resize(function() {
        var windowWidth = $window.width();

        if (windowWidth < 820 && !videoElement.paused) {
            videoElement.pause();
        }
        else if (windowWidth >= 820 && videoElement.paused) {
            videoElement.play();
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, when the window width is below `820px`, pause the video if it's currently not paused. I added some additional functionality to play it when the window size is `>= 820px`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where would this script be placed? In the header tag? Under my @media or inline next to the element?

Comment: Place it in your [jquery ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Read that page for the specifics and an example.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery function call adds an event handler to the window's resize function and then stops and hides the video.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(this).width() < 820)
            $(videoSelector)[0].pause().css({display:'none'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me where this script would be placed? I've tried putting it in the header and then within the html next to the video tag with a <script> tag and neither answer seems to function.

Comment: you need to wrap jquery functions in the `$(document).ready` event handler for them to work.  Try it now in either location

Comment: I tried this:  `code`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(this).width() < 820)
            $(videoSelector)[0].pause().css({display:'none'});
    });
});});
</script>`code`

Comment: but doesn't seem to function

Comment: also if that is in your "head", you might have issues with the semicolon after the `</script>`

Comment: yeah the http is there - it didn't come over when I copy and pasted - also no idea where that semi colon after the </script> tag is coming from that also is not in my actual code

Comment: Actually got both solutions to work so thank you for both  your answers - sorry that I can not mark both as answered!!